# How to get custom subdomain working on Wordpress with AWS Bitnami

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami

I installed a Bitnami / Wordpress instance on AWS, it all works great via the public IP but when I try and setup a subdomain I run into some issues, i'm following the instructions here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/wordpress/administration/configure-domain/

I update the `wp-config.php` file to `https://blog.domain.com/` (domain.com is replaced with my actual domain) like the instructions say. Looks like this:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://blog.domain.com/');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://blog.domain.com/');
```

Then in my DNS provider (CloudFlare) I set the `A Record` for `blog` to the `public IP`

However when I go to the url I see this:

[image: Bad Wordpress]

And when I go to the https://blog.domain.com/wp-admin I see this:

[image: Redirect Issu]

Note that `i'm not attempting to setup a Multisite environment` I just want one Wordpress instance setup on the sub-domain `https://blog.domain.dom`

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a WordPress question. The problem you are facing is the routing of the domain in apache - in general apache says where the website is eg. `app/wordpress/htdocs/{website}` (the website is in htdocs directory). What you need to do is change the `httpd.conf` to recognise the subdomain and also you need to add a subfolder where your subdomain will be pointing.

**!IMPORTANT! In bitnami stack the location of .conf file is different: `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf`**

I am not sure how your folder structure looks like but it will be probably something like this: `app/wordpress/htdocs/{main_website}` and for subdomain `app/wordpress/htdocs/blog/{blog_website}`

So in your httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/abc"

    ServerAdmin mail@example.com

    ServerName abc.your_domain.com

    ServerAlias www.abc.your_domain.com

    ErrorLog "logs/abc-error_log"

    CustomLog "logs/abc-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Source: https://community.bitnami.com/t/sub-domain-pointing-to-a-sub-folder/11796

I hope this helps.

Comment: Where do you usually find the httpd.conf file? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: Since its Bitnami it will be in `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` (I will make a correction in my answer). I just tested it with my own website and it all works.